# codeigniter mysql query problem

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I execute a simple insert query, however this insert is done multiple times sometimes unexpectedly.  The code for insert is :

```
$query=$this->db->query("INSERT INTO clientaccesshistory (jobid, clientid,firstname,lastname,clientname,menu,submenu,starttime) VALUES ('$time','$userID','$firstname','$lastname','$clientname','Monitor/Verify', '$this->job_name',current_timestamp() )");
```

When i look in the database though this information is sometimes there 3 times, sometimes its just once like it is supposed to be.  I think this is some issue with connecting to mysql, and then retries till it inserts three times?

I tested the front end to see if the function is actually be called more than once by putting an alert there, but no problem there whatsoever.

Comment: try putting an echo in the function and printing something to the ouput instead of alerting it.

Comment: tried it, the the function is being called once, its something within sql thats makign it insert three times with different time stamps

Comment: this INSERT statement will not add more than one record when executed once

Comment: Would a `die()` after the insert limit the number of inserted rows to only 1?

Comment: Try using active record instead of that statement to see if it inserts only one record or more.

Answer (score 0):

Your code almost certainly has to be in a variable loop of some kind.  This code, like wonk says, will not add more than one record, ever.

Comment: The only loop I have is at the browser side, there are nested loops to select a client, submenu, and finally run a job which triggers this database command, the loops have nothing to do with the database part

Comment: The only way to figure this out is to post more of your code.  This line by itself is not causing multiple insert.  To test it it try this line of code by itself without any other code.  Do have this code tied to an ajax call of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

This won't be of much help, but you can try using this-

```
$arr = array(
jobid => $time,
clientid => $userID,
firstname => $firstname,
lastname => $lastname,
clientname => $clientname,
menu => 'Monitor/Verify',
submenu => $this->job_name,
starttime => current_timestamp()
);

$this->db->insert('clientaccesshistory', $arr);
```

Comment: Then, like Caimen said in the following reply, it is definitely in some loop. You should try echoing some sort of text and see if it is getting printed thrice too.